# How to avoid multiple warning from gcc when I use pre-processing #warning in a .h

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I hope you are well.
I have a file version.h include in 5 files.c. 
When I compile I have 5 warnings:

> version.h:10:2: warning:-- SUB_VERSION2
>       version.h:10:2: warning:-- SUB_VERSION2
>       version.h:10:2: warning:-- SUB_VERSION2
>       version.h:10:2: warning:-- SUB_VERSION2
>       version.h:10:2: warning:-- SUB_VERSION2

and I want to have only one warning. I have looking on some website for a while and I find nothing about this problem. How to avoid this problem?

Here is my .h and my .c is random:

```
#ifndef _VERSION_H
#define _VERSION_H

#define SUB_VERSION 1
#define SUB_VERSION SUB_VERSION2

#if (SUB_VERSION == SUB_VERSION2)
   #ifndef WARNING_SUB_VERSION
     #define WARNING_SUB_VERSION
     #warning -- SUB_VERSION2
   #endif

#endif
  #endif
    #endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Logically, each `.c` file is compiled independently of the others. This implies that you can't issue a warning from the header file included in one, and have it suppressed in the others.

Comment: Your diagnosis certainly seems correct, but the conclusion "you can't" must rely on some unstated assumptions about what kinds of solutions should be considered.

Comment: thanks you for your feed back. Do you have any advice for resolve my problem ?

Comment: My assumption was that the OP didn't want to change the scenario of multiple .c files each including the same .h file. If OP is prepared to change that (as in your answer), then things change. However, I get the feeling that OP was looking for some kind of preprocessor magic. If so: "you can't".

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to split version.h into version.h and version.c.

**version.h** file:

```
#ifndef _VERSION_H
#define _VERSION_H

#define SUB_VERSION 1
#define SUB_VERSION SUB_VERSION2

#endif /* _VERSION_H */
```

**version.c** file:

```
#if (SUB_VERSION == SUB_VERSION2)
#    warning -- SUB_VERSION2
#endif
```

The version.c file is compiled only once. Since there is no warning in the header file any more, the total amount of warnings is reduced to one.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your header has a proper multiple-inclusion guard, it must be that your multiple warnings arise from compilation of multiple translation units (roughly, from separate C source files).  Each translation unit is compiled independently, so the multiple warnings are to be expected.

You could potentially reduce the number of warnings to one by combining all your sources into a single translation unit, but I don't particularly recommend this.

There are other possibilities related to the structure of your code, such as using macros and additional preprocessor conditionals to designate a specific translation unit -- maybe the one containing `main()` -- as the one for which the warning is emitted.  Approaches such as this are brittle, however, and I do not recommend them either.

Your best options are probably to either live with the multiple warnings or suppress them altogether.